# Determining how many bits is a processor by looking at the assembly listing file

Tags: architecture, assembly, cpu, microcontroller, cpu-architecture

In my introduction to computers class, we wrote an assembly program for the MC68332 microcontroller. I know this microcontroller is 32-bit because I read it in the datasheet. I was wondering if there is a way to determine this by looking at the LST file generated when assembling the asm source code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The first column ist the address of the instructions, the second group are the operations to be executed aka opcodes or instructions, and the last field are the instructions translated to human readable form, commonly known as assembly.

On this processor the opcodes consume usually a multiple of 16 bit (2 bytes), thats the reason you see only even addresses. Despite this, it is a 32 bit processor, this is mainly because of its address space of 2^32. This is the reason you see the addresses eight digits wide, each digit encodes 4 bits.

You can guess that it is a 32 bit processor from the `.L` suffix of some instructions, it is short for "long" which is usually 32 bit, so this processor has additionally the ability to process 32 bit wide instructions.

Answer (score 1):

the first number in those lines is obviously the address; the second (and third) the actual opcodes assembled. the reason the last two have two 16-bit words is the args $01 and $02. the CLR.L is a good hint that it is a 32-bit processor: "clear longword".

Comment: thank you, let's take the last line for example. 143c corresponds to the D2 register and 0002 to the value 2. is that right? I don't think so, since in the second line, CLR.L D2 translates to 4282. Can you pleace provide some more details?

Comment: no, 143c encodes move.b ,d2 and the 0002 is the value to move into d2. if your school did not provide you with the programmer's manual for your processor, it is very likely available online.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can't just tell from the assembly instructions or listing. If you need to look up the mnemonic, you are going to find out all about the instruction, and it is going to tell you about how many bits will be involved. But even then that may not be enough, as I could write a series of instructions or an IBM System z mainframe that only work with the lowest 1/4 of a 64-bit register, or deal with a single byte in storage, and you could not tell just from the code that the 16 general-purpose registers are 64-bit. Or ancient Honeywell Series 6000 code that might work with either 6 6-bit characters or 4 9-bit characters in a register, based on a flag bit in a control register.

This then leads to the best way to find out - read the spec sheet, Principles of Operation, or similar guide, and learn the instructions. And the more you learn, the more fun you realize it is to use assembler code.